# Tablesorter AJAX pagination. How to properly interact wiith a backend JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, tablesorter

Trying to make some of my tables work with [Ajax pagination](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html)
Actually created a clean empty template with just one table. Just for testing.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
  TEST Skaters averages - NHL stats tracker
{% endblock title %}

{% block styles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'players/tablesorter.css' %}">
{% endblock styles %}

{% block content %}
<!-- SKATERS       -->
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tablesorter-ignoreRow">
      <td class="pager" colspan="5">
        <button type="button" class="btn first"><i class="small material-icons">first_page</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn prev"><i class="small material-icons">navigate_before</i></button>
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn next"><i class="small material-icons white">navigate_next</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn last"><i class="small material-icons">last_page</i></button>
        <select class="pagesize">
          <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<!-- Widgets -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/extras/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'players/sorting_averages.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

sorting_averages.js

```
$("table")
  .tablesorter({

  });

.tablesorterPager({
  container: $(".pager"),
  ajaxUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/skaters_averages_json/{page}',
});
```

In players.views I'm making slices with JSON data for every page.

```
def skaters_averages_json(request, page):
    start = utils.PAGE_SIZE_2*(page - 1)
    end = start + utils.PAGE_SIZE_2

    skaters = Skater.objects.select_related('team')
    one_page_slice = skaters.order_by('-points', 'games', '-goals')[start:end]
    skaters_json = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', one_page_slice))

    data = {}
    data["total_rows"] = utils.PAGE_SIZE_2
    data["headers"] = ["ID", "Name", "Points"]
    data["rows"] = []

    for index, skater in enumerate(skaters_json):
        data["rows"].append({})
        data["rows"][index][data["headers"][0]] = skater['fields']['nhl_id']
        data["rows"][index][data["headers"][1]] = skater['fields']['name']
        data["rows"][index][data["headers"][2]] = skater['fields']['points']

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('skaters_averages_json/<int:page>', views.skaters_averages_json,
         name='skaters_averages_json'),
]
```

For example, 127.0.0.1:8000/skaters_averages_json/1 shows this JSON output

```
{
   "total_rows":25,
   "headers":[
      "ID",
      "Name",
      "Points"
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "ID":8476453,
         "Name":"Nikita Kucherov",
         "Points":128
      },
      {
         "ID":8478402,
         "Name":"Connor McDavid",
         "Points":116
      },
      {
         "ID":8474141,
         "Name":"Patrick Kane",
         "Points":110
      },
      {
         "ID":8477934,
         "Name":"Leon Draisaitl",
         "Points":105
      },
      {
         "ID":8473419,
         "Name":"Brad Marchand",
         "Points":100
      },
      {
         "ID":8471675,
         "Name":"Sidney Crosby",
         "Points":100
      },
      {
         "ID":8477492,
         "Name":"Nathan MacKinnon",
         "Points":99
      },
      {
         "ID":8476346,
         "Name":"Johnny Gaudreau",
         "Points":99
      },
      {
         "ID":8474564,
         "Name":"Steven Stamkos",
         "Points":98
      },
      {
         "ID":8477493,
         "Name":"Aleksander Barkov",
         "Points":96
      },
      {
         "ID":8478483,
         "Name":"Mitchell Marner",
         "Points":94
      },
      {
         "ID":8478010,
         "Name":"Brayden Point",
         "Points":92
      },
      {
         "ID":8476456,
         "Name":"Jonathan Huberdeau",
         "Points":92
      },
      {
         "ID":8471218,
         "Name":"Blake Wheeler",
         "Points":91
      },
      {
         "ID":8471214,
         "Name":"Alex Ovechkin",
         "Points":89
      },
      {
         "ID":8475166,
         "Name":"John Tavares",
         "Points":88
      },
      {
         "ID":8478420,
         "Name":"Mikko Rantanen",
         "Points":87
      },
      {
         "ID":8478550,
         "Name":"Artemi Panarin",
         "Points":87
      },
      {
         "ID":8473512,
         "Name":"Claude Giroux",
         "Points":85
      },
      {
         "ID":8476460,
         "Name":"Mark Scheifele",
         "Points":84
      },
      {
         "ID":8478427,
         "Name":"Sebastian Aho",
         "Points":83
      },
      {
         "ID":8470613,
         "Name":"Brent Burns",
         "Points":83
      },
      {
         "ID":8478403,
         "Name":"Jack Eichel",
         "Points":82
      },
      {
         "ID":8477497,
         "Name":"Sean Monahan",
         "Points":82
      },
      {
         "ID":8473548,
         "Name":"Phil Kessel",
         "Points":82
      }
   ]
}
```

As I read in the docs linked above, now ajaxProcessing isn't necessary

> OBJECT returned
>
> In v2.11, the ajaxProcessing can just return the above object directly
>   (or don't even bother setting an ajaxProcessing function).
>   So, if an object is returned by the ajaxProcessing function, the data
>   is stored in table.config.pager.ajaxData

It seems to me that I misunderstood how to pass a page number parameter in `.tablesorterPager`. Tried a couple of different ways. For now, I would like the table to show the first page on the initial load. And then paginate back and forth using AJAX. Now it loads just the headers of the table. Not headers from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you will need to include an [`ajaxProcessing` function](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing).

If you want to completely leave out the `ajaxProcessing` function, then the JSON expected from the server should look like this (comments aren't allowed in JSON of course):

```
{
  total: 100,
  filteredRows: 100, // needed if using the filter widget
  headers: [...], // optional
  rows: [...]
}
```

or this

```
[
  100, // total
  [
    [ "row1cell1", "row1cell2", ... "row1cellN" ],
    [ "row2cell1", "row2cell2", ... "row2cellN" ],
    ...
    [ "rowNcell1", "rowNcell2", ... "rowNcellN" ]
  ],
  [ "header1", "header2", ... "headerN" ] // optional
]
```

Comment: I'm just realized that there is an extra semicolon in `sorting_averages.js`.  `$("table").tablesorter({  });`. The tablesorter wasn't even initialized.

Comment: Table body is contains just `500 Internal Server Error`. Do I need to write a proper AJAX success handler myself? Or this should work only with `ajaxUrl`?

Comment: Also, `console.log` prints the message `Invalid or incorrect number of columns in the THEAD; expected 3, but found 5 columns         jquery.tablesorter.js:2357:13`   There is no such error when I add two more `th` to the table in the HTML. Not sure where it found 5 columns initially.

Comment: To answer my own question, I should use [ajaxObject](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxobject) property. But the interaction should work without it if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: * I just realized

Comment: Don't need to use `ajaxObject` at all. Just learned how to debug AJAX in Firefox DE. The response of this AJAX request contained 'AssertionError at /skaters_averages_json/0  Negative indexing is not supported.` So, I just added +1 to the `{page}` parameter. `ajaxUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/skaters_averages_json/{page+1}'` And it loads the first page perfectly fine. But pager doesn't seem to be there, [screen](https://yadi.sk/i/BvephVcTaEzy8w). But that's another problem.

Comment: Btw, the message about 5 columns is still there.

Comment: Hmm, I thought, that in `total`, we should pass a number of rows we would like to see on one page, not the number of rows in all pages. That is why pager wasn't working. With `data["total"] = skaters.count()` it works like a charm! [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNNo7_lbFBw)

Answer (score 0):

@Mottie posted a great answer. And I'd like to add a couple of things that were wrong in my code.

1. In my players.views I didn't expect to get a value of the parameter 'page' = 0.
   I forgot that tablesorter's rows indexation starts from 0. Then when pager made AJAX call with `page=0` variable `start` was equal -25. It's obviously wrong. With `utils. PAGE_SIZE_2 = 25` `start` = 25*(0 - 1). If `page = 1` it `start = 0`. So I've just replaced `page` with `page+1` and it works as expected.
2. The semicolon in this tablesorter initialization caused the `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'` So nothing in this file could be executed. With the semicolon removed it works.

   `$("table").tablesorter({ 
   });`